# Display Image from a Network Directory in a Web Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

We currently have a store of images on a network directory and the path to those images stored in a db. I have a web app that needs to display these images to the users and i was wondering if this was possible and how i should i go about doing something like this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult GetImage(string imageName)
{
    return File(dirPath+imageName,"image/jpeg"); //or other mime type
}
```

Make sure you perform decent validation on `imageName` so that you don't accidentally expose parts of your filesystem you'd rather not. For instance if `imageName` is `..\..\web.config` (for instance), you're in trouble.

Comment: LOL sorry i forgot the actual error: "Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Images\010101.JPG'. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException

Comment: Does the IIS user have access to that path?

Comment: How would i check if it does?

Comment: Is D: a mapped network share or an actual drive on the web server?